# Controlling VLC via c#

Tags: c#, vlc

I am writing an application that will open vlc, add a file to its playlist, and play it. I am having a few issues on the last 2.

```
 AXVLC.VLCPlugin alxplugin1 = new AXVLC.VLCPlugin();

                alxplugin1.addTarget("C:\\test.avi", null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListInsert, 0);
                alxplugin1.play();
```

This isn't working... Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC

Answer (score 4):

The newer version of VLC needs "file:///" in beginning of the file name. It should work if you add this. Please try the following and see if it solves your problem.
use:
 `alxplugin1.addTarget("file:///" + "C:\\test.avi", null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayL­istReplaceAndGo,0);`

Comment: That worked for me. Unfortunately, none of the wrappers documented this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

C# can access VLC through it's COM layer. First thing to do is to register the axvlc.dll. Open a cmd window and type:

```
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\axvlc.dll
```

You should receive a dialog confirming that your dll was registered successfully. Open VisualStudio and create a new WinForms project and add a reference to the COM VLC COM object. Go to the Form cs file

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
          public Form1()
          {
               InitializeComponent();

               AXVLC.VLCPlugin2Class p = new AXVLC.VLCPlugin2Class();
               p.addTarget("C:\\zk.m4a", null, VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListInsert, 0);
               p.play();
           }
     }
 }
```

Note: The VLCPluginClass was deprecated, use VLCPlugin2Class

Comment: Tried this, but getting `Interop type 'AXVLC.VLCPlugin2Class' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.` from the compiler.

Comment: To remove the  "Interop type 'AXVLC.VLCPlugin2Class' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead" error. Right click the AXVLC reference and goto properties. Make the "Embedded Interops Type" to false.