# Suggestions for a video montage application (extracting and playing randomized short clips from a playlist)?

Tags: c#, .net, video, directx, vlc

I'm an electronics engineer used to coding in embedded C and assembly, but I decided to start learning higher-level stuff like C#, .NET, etc., so I can start making software as a hobby. I have a great idea for one of my first projects, but after searching several forums for days on end, I'm left not really knowing what would be the easiest path forward.

The functionality that I'm looking to create is pretty similar to the idea of a photo slideshow, but applied to videos instead. The program would open a playlist or a folder full of videos and then play the videos in a random order, starting from a random starting position, and with a fixed duration (let's say 10 seconds as an example). You would end up being able to watch a sort of "video montage" that consisted of small clips from random parts of the videos in the playlist, shown in a random order, ad infinitum until the program is closed.

There are a number of ways I could tackle the problem:

- Develop a standalone video player with the fixed functionality of showing "video slideshows." DirectX has the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback API that
  could be a good starting point. I found an example here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/111181-adding-video-to-an-application/
- Modify an open source project to add the desired functionality. I've seen a few cool projects that could get me started, like this simple C# Movie Player: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18552/C-Movie-Player
- Use a scripting interface to implement this functionality on an existing media player, like VLC or Winamp. You could also control VLC via C#, like the example here: [Controlling VLC via c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043922/controlling-vlc-via-c-sharp)

I realize that the obvious answer for most people would be to "use whatever you're most comfortable with," but since I'm a pure beginner, I don't really have any allegiances to a particular language or development environment. So, I was just curious if anybody had an idea of what might be the least painful option for a beginner.

I also apologize that this is not a very specific programming question. I'm sort of just testing the waters to get my footing. Hopefully, once I get started on the project, I'll be able to come back and post more intelligent and relevant questions!

Answer (score 0):

While your background would lend you toward C#, I recommend investigating something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20478/A-simple-WPF-media-player-with-media-item-list) and using WPF for the media player. You can then control the media player using a background worker in order to stop the video or queue up the next one. Some other .NET concepts that will be of use to you are FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects, to provide you with the necessary information about the files. I'm not sure if you've had experience with generic data structures in .NET, but the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace would be a good place to start to get a feel for data structure you want to keep your playlist in. WPF will also be able to help you with transitions between video clips.

Admittedly WPF is easier with an understanding of the MVVM or MVC design patterns, but I think you'll be able to get something working without having to delve too far into that right up front.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely give that tutorial a try and post back here when I have made some progress.