# How to play videos in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to know how to play videos dynamically in asp.net. in my project gave provision to add videos.path of videos will be in project and videos saved in one of folders in application named videos.I displayed them also.when clicks each item i want to run that particular video.used flash player object and vlc media player object .but its not coming in all systems.How to do this searched many times in internet but didnt get any useful link.How to do this?

Thanks in Advance
Amrutha

Comment: You are saving Video in folder with with extensions?  can you please tell the extension of that file

Comment: what has been edited??? @ jhon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043922/controlling-vlc-via-c-sharp

Comment: HiThanks for the response..Im saving files with extensions wmv,wma,mp4,and flv

Answer (score 0):

you can use an embedded iframe you tube player which will have the src to your video file and also lot of parameters that you can use.

check this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

using iframes gives you advantage for playing videos on multiple browsers with no extra add-ons required.

Comment: hi thanks for the response ..its a new concept for me.I will try this

Comment: hi i tried youtube player and its working too but actually i want palyer which works without internet.Is this possible?

Comment: i think this could help you..[link](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/13/embedding-flash)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  id="DivVideoPlay" ></div></div>
<script src="../jwplayer/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jwplayer("DivVideoPlay").setup({
    flashplayer: "../jwplayer/player.swf",
    file: "../Media/Videosgallary/video1.flv",
    height: 663,
    width: 953
});

</script>
```

you can download jwplayer.js [here]: http://aussikhsupport.org/jwplayer/jwplayer.js

place http://aussikhsupport.org/jwplayer/player.swf  in same folder where jwplayer.js placed