# VLC player doesn't play any video

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc

I added the VLC plugin from COM Component, dragged it to my form, added two buttons to the form ("Play" and "Stop"), and wrote the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axVLC.AutoPlay = false;
    axVLC.playlist.add(@"C:\Users\Hanif\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Education Visualization\Vlc\Resources\Video1.wmv");
}

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axVLC.playlist.play();
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axVLC.playlist.stop();
}
```

But when I click on "Play", nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: related: [Controlling VLC via c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043922/controlling-vlc-via-c-sharp)

Comment: Breaking on thrown exceptions is enabled? x32 build with x32 ActiveX component? ActiveX control is sized correctly? Any audio coming out?

Answer (score 16):

Is the VLC plugin of type `AxAXVLC.AxVLCPlugin2`? If yes, then try these:

1) try playing video of other formats, e.g. .avi, .mkv, etc.

2) try adding `file:///` in the beginning of URI:

```
@"file:///C:\Users\Hanif\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Education Visualization\Vlc\Resources\Video1.wmv"
```

3) try adding 2 more arguments in the add command:

```
axVLC.playlist.add(@"C:\Users\Hanif\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Education Visualization\Vlc\Resources\Video1.wmv", null, null);
```

Comment: I have been looking for this solution for eons! Your answer is the only one that worked! I can't express my gratitude enough for your help! GOD BLESS YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Playing a local file works only if its path is preceded by "file:///", not otherwise. Discovered this after much fight. Here is the code:

```
string f = @"file:///D:\abc.mp4";
string f2 = @"file:///D:\def.avi";
int i = VLCPlayer.playlist.add(f);
int j = VLCPlayer.playlist.add(f2);

VLCPlayer.playlist.playItem(j);  // to play def.avi
//VLCPlayer.playlist.play();  // to play abc.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axVLC.playlist.playNext();
}
```