# VLC rc interface sockets - Connection refused

Tags: c#, sockets, vlc

I am trying to write a simple remote control interface to VLC in c#. The .net wrapper around libVLC seemed a little out of date, but [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043922/controlling-vlc-via-c-sharp) details how to control vlc via a socket connection (I have included my code below, almost entirely ripped from the other post at the moment)

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var socketAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 35913);
        var vlcServerProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe", $"-I rc --rc-host {socketAddress}");

        try
        {
            var vlcRcSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            vlcRcSocket.Connect(socketAddress);
            // start another thread to look for responses and display them
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Receive(vlcRcSocket));

            Console.WriteLine("Connected. Enter VLC commands.");

            while (true)
            {
                string command = Console.ReadLine();
                if (command.Equals("quit")) break;
                Send(vlcRcSocket, command);
            }

            Send(vlcRcSocket, "quit"); // close vlc rc interface and disconnect
            vlcRcSocket.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            vlcServerProcess.Kill();
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket socket, string command)
    {
        // send command to vlc socket, note \n is important
        byte[] commandData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}\n", command));
        int sent = socket.Send(commandData);
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket socket)
    {
        do
        {
            if (socket.Connected == false)
                break;
            // check if there is any data
            bool haveData = socket.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead);

            if (haveData == false) continue;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (haveData)
                {
                    int received = socket.Receive(buffer);
                    mem.Write(buffer, 0, received);
                    haveData = socket.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray()));
            }

        } while (true);
    }
}
```

However, my app always throws an exception on the line `vlcRcSocket.Connect(socketAddress);` the exception that is thrown is

> **System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException:**
>   'No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it'

I have tried different port numbers, and even disabling my firewall, but it doesn't seem to help. I can see the instance of VLC running in the task manager, but I can't see the binding in `netstat` so I'm not sure if VLC is listening? Am I doing it wrong, or is there a better approach to controlling an instance of VLC? (I only want some basic control, start, stop, skip and volume really)

Comment: You can't use loopback for a client application (IPAddress.Loopback).  The Net library always give the error.  Use the IP address or Computer name.

Comment: @jdweng Ah, very annoying, thank for letting me know. However, I have updated to find the ip address of the machine on the network and use that and it is still giving the same error

Comment: The error is a general error that a connection could not complete.  Try the computer name and see if that works.  The server application also has to be started before the client is started.  Then you have to make sure nobody else is using the port number.  Try from cmd.exe : Netstat -a.  Then also from cmd.exe try Ping.  If you are using more than one PC try all the commands from server.  Sometimes Ping will work in one direction and not the other.